# LDAP configuration in Keycloak

Tags: java, ldap, connection, keycloak

I am trying to to configure LDAP in user federations of keycloak. I started my apache directory server and connecting to it. But I am unable to connect with it. I tried
ldap://localhost:10389
ldap://localhost:389
ldap://127.0.0.1:10389
ldap://192.168.29.244:10389(my ip address)
[keycloak user federation config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79sWi.png)

I tried the above connection urls with port 10389 and just 389 but getting same error.
I want to know what mistake i am doing.